# Setting specific RGB values using Image function in R

Tags: r, image, matrix, rgb

I have a  Matrix  (NxM) and I want to create an image out of the values of the matrix ! How can I set specific RGB values for specific values of the Matrix ?

For Example :
RGB (128/128/128) for values<0 
RGB (128/96/0) for values [0,0.7) 
and so on !

Should I use Image function by changin the col parameters or is there any other easier fuction I could use ?

I have found this :

```
    # plot reclassified data
plot(chm_classified,
     legend = FALSE,
     col = c("red", "blue", "green"), axes = FALSE,
     main = "Classified Canopy Height Model \n short, medium, tall trees")
```

from : https://earthdatascience.org/courses/earth-analytics/lidar-raster-data-r/classify-raster/

how can i set specific RGB values for the colors I want instead of "RED" , "Green " , "Blue"

Comment: You mean you want a grid with colored cells as in this image: http://resources.esri.com/help/9.3/arcgisdesktop/com/gp_toolref/geoprocessing_with_3d_analyst/Reclass_Reclass2.gif ?

Comment: Yes and in the output Raster I want specific RGB Values for values >=5 in the matrix  for exaple ! I want to now how to specify the RGB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand. Do you want something like this:

```
M <- matrix(rnorm(100), 10, 10)
Mcolors <- apply(M, 1:2, 
                 function(x) ifelse(x>0,
                                    rgb(128,128,128,maxColorValue=255),
                                    rgb(0,0,255, maxColorValue=255)))

library(plotrix)
color2D.matplot(M, cellcolors=Mcolors)
```

[image]

Comment: In this solution how do I set multiple parameters ( If I want to set 5 differert colors for example ) ? I thought something like : Mcolors <- apply(M, 1:5, 
function(x) ifelse (x<0,rgb(128,128,128,maxColorValue=255),
                    ifelse(x>=0 & x<=0.2, rgb(128,96,0,maxColorValue = 255),
                           ifelse(x>0.2&x<=0.3, rgb(255,255,0,maxColorValue = 255),
                                  ifelse(x>0.3&x<=0.5 ,rgb(146,208,80,maxColorValue = 255),rgb(84,130,53,maxColorValue = 255)))))) ..... But it returns me error

Comment: @ΑναστασιοςΚούσας Yes, you can nest the `ifelse`'s. What is the error you get ?

Comment: Ah maybe `apply(M, 1:5`. That makes no sense. Do `apply(M, 1:2`.

Comment: Yes that worked ! I thought since I wanted to set 5 different parameters about the colours the Margin should be set 1:5 ! No matter what thank you very much !

Comment: @ΑναστασιοςΚούσας You're welcome. To thank me, you could click the checkmark to accept the answer and also upvote :)